# Going directly to page vs clicking on a button to go to that page

Tags: navigation, tabs, visual-design

On my website i have a tab menu which has 3 tabs across. The third tab takes them to a table where they can view their subscriptions to a certain product. This is where I'm scratching my head should the user

A. be able to go to the table and subscribe from there (e.g the user goes to the table tab and on that table maybe on the top left have a button that they can click to "Sign up for another subscription") where it would take them to a form OR

B. Hover over the tab and have a drop down that let them go to the table by clicking Table and also lets them "Sign up for another subscription" without going to the table but straight from the dropdown.

They would both take you to the same sign up form. I just wanted to know which one has a better flow from the Users perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my perspective, navigation is main controller of the website. it has to carry any information not a question.

Why don't you go for creating a signup and subscription on top of your page or in the footer.

any how that depends on the requirement.
in your view option B is suitable for your requirement where user can see sign in and subscription as an option instead of main navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Your tabs have names which are sign posts and navigation triggers to specific pages/features which contain functionality, e.g. Subscriptions

Option A is much simpler:

- Choose Subscriptions by clicking the tab
- Choose what you want to do about Subscriptions on the Subscription page by interacting with subscription features on the subscription page

This keeps all the subscription functionality on the page you navigated to.

Your option B is adding an additional purpose to the tab via the mouse-over which reveals a drop-down menu, which is now overloading the simple purpose of the tab, and is likely to cause some confusion. Confusion causes usability issues.